# Add events back after removing them with off()

Tags: jquery

I have a feature that displays/hides a hoverbox below an element on mouseenter/mouseleave, and over the same element if the user clicks the element.

I've managed to remove the mouseenter/mouseleave events with the click event, but can't figure a way to add them back if the user clicks to dismiss the hoverbox.

How can I get the mouseenter/mouseleave events back when the user clicks on the hoverbox to dismiss it?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n2fole00/2hn906kg/)

**jQuery**

```
// add hoverbox on click
$('.icon').on('click', function() {
  var $iconPosition = $(this).position(); // position on clicked icon
  //console.log($iconPosition)
  // set hoverbox position based on current icon position and make visible
  $('.hoverbox').offset({
    top: $iconPosition.top + 10,
    left: $iconPosition.left
  }).css({
    "display": "block"
  });

  $('.icon').off('mouseenter mouseleave'); // remove mouseenter mouseleave functionality 
});

// remove hoverbox on click
$('.hoverbox').on('click', function() {
  // reset offset or it will accumulate after each click
  $('.hoverbox').offset({
    top: 0,
    left: 0
  }).css({
    "display": "none"
  });
});

// add hoverbox on mouseenter
$('.icon').on('mouseenter', function() {
  var $iconPosition = $(this).position(); // position on clicked icon
  //console.log($iconPosition)
  // set hoverbox position based on current icon position and make visible
  $('.hoverbox').offset({
    top: $iconPosition.top + 130,
    left: $iconPosition.left
  }).css({
    "display": "block"
  });
});

// remove hoverbox on mouseleave
$('.icon').on('mouseleave', function() {
  // reset offset or it will accumulate after each click
  $('.hoverbox').offset({
    top: 0,
    left: 0
  }).css({
    "display": "none"
  });
});
```

Comment: IMHO: Generally add/remove events is a pain.  It so much easier to either disable an element click, turn off events or have a javascript variable to determine if an event should fire then adding/removing listeners.

Comment: Also you can manage states like `$('.icon.opened').on('mouseleave'` and `$('.icon:not(.opened)').on('mousenter'` ... $(.icon).addClass('opened'); });`

Comment: @SerCrAsH If you're changing classes dynamically you need to use event delegation. `$('.icon.opened')` selects all the icons that were opened at the time you established the handler, it won't take changes into account.

Comment: ^^^ Delegates all the way.  `$(someParentSelector).on('mouseenter', '.icon:not(.disabled)', ...);` and then just add the disabled class to the icon when you want it to be "turned off"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments have suggested alternatives to adding and removing the handler. But if you really want to do that, you should put the handler function in a named function. Then you can easily add it back.

```js
function mouseLeaveHandler() {
  // ...
}

function mouseEnterHandler() {
  // ...
}

$(".icon").on({
  mouseenter: mouseEnterHandler,
  mouseleave: mouseLeaveHandler
});

// add hoverbox on click
$('.icon').on('click', function() {
  var $iconPosition = $(this).position(); // position on clicked icon
  //console.log($iconPosition)
  // set hoverbox position based on current icon position and make visible
  $('.hoverbox').offset({
    top: $iconPosition.top + 10,
    left: $iconPosition.left
  }).css({
    "display": "block"
  });

  $('.icon').off('mouseenter mouseleave'); // remove mouseenter mouseleave functionality 
});

// remove hoverbox on click
$('.hoverbox').on('click', function() {
  // reset offset or it will accumulate after each click
  $('.hoverbox').offset({
    top: 0,
    left: 0
  }).css({
    "display": "none"
  });

  $(".icon").on({
    mouseenter: mouseEnterHandler,
    mouseleave: mouseLeaveHandler
  });

});
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm not really sure how this works, but I'll set it up and play around with it, and I'm sure I'll figure it out.

Comment: Ok, I had a chance to play with it. It's working nice. I didn't realise .on() could take an object of events like that. I also see the importance of having named events for such occasions. Thanks.